# Paginate and collect posts and comments from Facebook (Python, Json)

Tags: python, json, facebook, pagination

I can't quite work out how to paginate and collect data from Facebook for my project. I know that I've got to make a loop in order to collect  it, but it doesn't seem to be working and I can't work out what's wrong. Here's my code:

```
import requests
import facebook
import json

def some_action(post):
    print posts['data']
    print post['created_time']

#Token
access_token = 'INSERT ACCESS TOKEN'
user = 'INSERT NAME'

#Posts
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')

x=0
while x < 500:
    y=0
    while y < 500:
        try:
            posts = requests.get(posts['paging']['previous']).json()


            y = y+1

            while True:
                posts = requests.get(posts['paging']['next']).json()
                with open('aa10.txt', 'a') as textfile:
                    json.dump(posts, textfile)
        except KeyError:
            break
x = x+1
```

Any idea on what I need to change? I know i need to edit the "paging" string specifically somehow. The issue here is pagination and the limit=25. Does anyone know how I can go about increasing this slightly?